# Can I add arbitrary directory to icon search dirs?

Tags: linux, icons, conventions

Linux desktop environments such as GNOME, KDE, XFCE etc search icon themes in some standard paths such as `/usr/share/icons`, `~/.icons`, `~/.local/share/icons` etc.

I wonder if I can add any directory to those paths for the DE to search for icons themes? For example, can I store an icon theme in `~/Icons` and get the DE find the icon theme?

I know overlaying will work. I already did that. I really want a directory to be added to those path instead.

Comment: That depends on the GUI applications (window managers, file managers...) you use. There is no such thing as "Linux desktops", nor does Linux search for icons.

Comment: @Quasímodo Yes I know that. By Linux desktop I meant KDE, GNOME, XFCE" etc desktop environments

I don't think that depends on GUI applications. It's controlled by much low level components I believe, like fontconfig for fonts

Comment: If desktop environments is what you meant, it is good idea to edit the question with the precise term to guarantee conveying the right idea. I really did not understand you at first, no nit-picking there.

Comment: @Quasímodo Edited the question. Check if its cleared

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.  I ran

```
apropos icon
```

in the terminal; here are the more promising results:

```
File::IconTheme (3pm) - find icon directories
xdg-desktop-icon (1) - command line tool for (un)installing icons to the desktop
xdg-icon-resource (1) - command line tool for (un)installing icon resources
```

So I tried

```
man File::IconTheme
```

and based on the info there, I wrote this short perl script and saved it as `icons.perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "icon paths:\n";
use File::IconTheme qw(xdg_icon_theme_search_dirs);
print join "\n", xdg_icon_theme_search_dirs, "\n";

print "user icon directory:\n";
use File::BaseDir qw(data_dirs);
print scalar data_dirs('icons');

print "\n"
```

Then back in the terminal, I ran

```
perl icons.perl
```

which on my system yields:

```
icon paths:
/home/user/.local/share/icons
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/icons
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/icons
/usr/share/icons
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/icons
/usr/share/pixmaps

user icon directory:
/home/user/.local/share/icons
```

Not sure if this answers your question, but maybe it points you in a better direction.  I would run `apropos icon` and see if you find anything else useful.

Comment: Thank you. It finds the directories icon theme is searched for by default. I want to add any arbitrary directory to these paths.

Comment: You could create a symbolic link to your arbitrary directory from the "user icon directory" returned by the above perl script.

Comment: Sorry, stackexchange timed me out on editing my own comment... You should be able to create a symbolic link to your arbitrary directory from within the "user icon directory" returned by the above perl script.  So, using the above as an example, navigate to `/home/user/.local/share/icons` directory in your terminal and do `ln -sT _my-icons-dir_ my-icons`.